# Why does ResNet models have consecutive BatchNormalization layers?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras, resnet

I was going through the ResNet architecture, and found that ResNet models tend to have pairs of consecutive BatchNorm layers, after certain intervals. I can't see any particular reason to do so, since:-

1. A BN layer normalizes the layer activations and then scales them using the parameters *beta* and *gamma*.
2. The First BN layer does this; it normalizes the incoming activations and then scales it to a Mean(*beta*) and Standard Deviation(gamma). The second BN then again normalizes the first BN's output (thus, reverting any scaling that the first BN layer did), and again moves it to a different mean and std with its new values of *beta* and *gamma*?

In the attached picture, only one such pair of BN layers is shown(*conv2_block1_0_bn* and *conv2_block1_3_bn*), but there are multiple pairs deeper into the network.[image]

Comment: Notice that the two 'consecutive' BN layers are connected to actually different layers. That might have something to do with it(?)

Comment: @DarthCadeus I think that is it. Stupid of me to not notice that they are in-fact connected to different layers. As a result, they are functioning quite independent of each other. The 2 BN layers activations are then being added below. If you would kindly give your answer below, I could mark it solved. Thanks a lot for the help!